# Difference of mock() vs. provide() in ng-mocks

Tags: angular, testing, mocking, ng-mocks

What is the difference between

https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockBuilder#mock

```
MockBuilder(TargetService, TargetModule)
  .mock(Service2, { trigger: () => 'mock2' })
```

and

https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockBuilder#provide

```
MockBuilder(TargetService, TargetModule)
  .provide({ provide: Service2, useValue: { trigger: () => 'mock2' }})
```

Comment: I'm assuming the 2 lines do the same thing with the difference that `.provide()` can take a real service as a parameter, while `.mock()` always creates a mock of the service.

Comment: `provide` is intended to add **additional** providers. `mock` is intended to mock **existing** providers. The same is shown as comment on [Github][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/help-me-mom/ng-mocks/blob/master/libs/ng-mocks/src/lib/mock-builder/types.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.mock`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockBuilder#mock) will replace the declaration with a mock at its definition, even if it's deeply nested NgModules.

[`.provide`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockBuilder#provide) simply adds the declaration to `providers` of TestBed and doesn't do any additional replacements in imported NgModules.